# What is the default admin password for the official glassfish docker from dockerhub

Tags: glassfish, dockerhub

I pulled the docker image for glassfish from [dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/glassfish/).The readme doesnt contain the password for admin, and the [documentation](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/tree/master/glassfish) doesn't either.

I have tried the following combinations:

> admin:admin
>
> admin: adminadmin
>
> admin: some long text inside the glassfish server local-password
>
> admin: leave blank

and nothing...

What is the password for the default admin for this docker image.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the default password for all glassfish 4.1 servers is

> admin: (leave blank)

my issue was I was trying to access the admin console remotely. Glassfish does not allow this. I had to run the following commands and restart my domain and everything worked fine after.

```
asadmin change-admin-password --domain_name [DOMAIN_NAME]
asadmin enable-secure-admin --port [PORT_NAME]
```

Answer (score 1):

adminadmin is the default password. You can change the password for the domain using the below command.

```
 asadmin change-admin-password --domain_name <domain-name>
```